# how to overcome No secret key error in git?

Tags: git, gnupg, secret-key

While using commit in VSCode I'm getting a `NO SECRET KEY` error.

[image]

As I'm trying to commit the changes and trying to push the changes to my GitHub repository I'm getting a `NO SECRET KEY` error.
How can I fix it?

Comment: If you do not have to GPG-sign commits, turn off whatever it is that tells VSCode to tell Git to GPG-sign commits. If you *do* have to GPG-sign commits, set up your GPG key using GPG. Git itself is merely attempting to obey your requirement that commits be GPG-signed, but for that to work, you must set up your GPG subsystem (not part of Git itself).

Answer (score -1):

The "No secret key" error in Git usually occurs when you are trying to push changes to a repository that is configured to use SSH authentication, but you don't have a valid SSH keypair configured on your local machine.

To fix this error, you'll need to generate an SSH keypair and add the public key to your Git hosting service (e.g., GitHub, GitLab, etc.). Here's a general outline of the steps you can follow to do this:

Open a terminal window and run the ssh-keygen command. This will generate a new SSH keypair and prompt you to enter a file in which to save the keys.

Follow the prompts to set the passphrase for your SSH keypair (optional).

Go to your Git hosting service's website and log in to your account.

Navigate to the SSH keys settings page, which is usually located under "Settings" or "Profile Settings".

Click the "Add SSH key" button and follow the prompts to add your public SSH key to your account.

Test your SSH connection by running the ssh -T git@ command, replacing  with the hostname of your Git hosting service (e.g., ssh -T git@github.com for GitHub).

If you've set up your SSH keypair correctly, you should now be able to push changes to your repository without encountering the "No secret key" error.

If you're still having trouble, it's possible that your local Git configuration is using the wrong SSH key or that there's an issue with your SSH configuration. You can try checking your local Git configuration with the git config -l command, and you can troubleshoot your SSH configuration by running the ssh -vT git@ command, which will provide verbose output that may help you identify any issues.

Comment: The error message is about GPG, that is it's about a key to sign commits, not SSH key for pushing.

Comment: as im using http is ssh key requried

Comment: @SWAPNILKULKARNI 1. No, SSH keys are for `ssh://` protocol. For `https://` protocol you need Personal Access Tokens. 2. The error message is about GPG, not HTTPS, not SSH.

Comment: so what to do??